# Click function in backstopjs not working while trying to log in using backstopjs

Tags: puppeteer, visual-testing

I am trying to log in to the system to navigate to the next page for visual test in backstopjs. For some reason I cannot perform click function as backstopjs doesn't detect my click command.
Following is the backstop.json snippet for the relevant action
`{
      "label": "Faethm Dashboard",
      "cookiePath": "backstop_data/engine_scripts/cookies.json",
      "url": "https://xxxxxx.com.au/dickyco",
      "keyPressSelectors": [
          {
                 "selector": "#email",
                 "keyPress": "Xxxxxxxxx@gmsil.com"
              },
               {
                  "selector": "#password",
                     "keyPress": "abcd!"
               },
                {
                  "selector":".ant-btn sc-kEYyzF hTZeXz",
                  "keyPress":"click()"
                }`

I get following error in my terminal

```
    Puppeteer encountered an error while running scenario "Faethm Dashboard"
TimeoutError: waiting for selector "body.root " failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded
      COMMAND | Executing core for "report"
      compare | Reference image not found Test_Faethm_Dashboard_0__0_appleMacPro.png
      compare | OK: Faethm Homepage Test_Faethm_Homepage_0_document_0_appleMacPro.png
       report | Test completed...
       report | 1 Passed
       report | 1 Failed
       report | Writing browser report
       report | Resources copied
       report | Copied configuration to: /Users/faethm/Desktop/VisualTest/backstopjs-example/backstop_data/html_report/config.js
      COMMAND | Executing core for "openReport"
   openReport | Attempting to ping 
   openReport | Remote not found. Opening backstop_data/html_report/index.html
       report | *** Mismatch errors found ***
      COMMAND | Command "report" ended with an error after [0.112s]
      COMMAND | Error: Mismatch errors found.
                    at /Users/faethm/Desktop/VisualTest/backstopjs-example/node_modules/backstopjs/core/command/report.js:116:17
                    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
      COMMAND | Command "test" ended with an error after [34.755s]
      COMMAND | Error: Mismatch errors found.
                    at /Users/faethm/Desktop/VisualTest/backstopjs-example/node_modules/backstopjs/core/command/report.js:116:17
                    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! backstopjs-example@1.0.0 test:visual: `rm -rf backstop_data/bitmaps_test && backstop test`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the backstopjs-example@1.0.0 test:visual script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/faethm/.npm/_logs/2018-11-27T00_46_49_521Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing your click from "keyPressSelectors" section, and using the built in clickSelector property after.

"clickSelector": ".ant-btn sc-kEYyzF hTZeXz"